# Reload Spring MVC response page in jQuery Dialog

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, spring-mvc, dialog

i am trying to submit a form with jQuery to a Spring MVC Controller Method and load the response page in a div tag of a dialog.

**jquery in dialog**

```
$("#findbtn").click(function() {
    $("#content").load($("#searchform").submit());
});
```

**Form**

```
 <form id="searchform" method="POST" action="/select">
                <input type="text" id="csearch" name="csearch" /><input
                    type="button" id="findbtn" />
    </form>
```

Controllermethod

```
@RequestMapping(value = "select", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String getSelection(Model model, @RequestParam("csearch") String find) {

    model.addAttribute("list", list);
    return "/select";
}
```

The Problem is that the response page is shown as a new page and not in the dialog. Is there a way to load it in the dialog.

Note: The response page (/select), happens to be the same page as the current loaded page in the dialog. That means i want to reload the content of the dialog with the same page, except the list is different.

thanks

Comment: What dialog are you using?  Jquery UI Dialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using JQuery `load` correctly (and its not the right method for what you want to do). `$.load()` takes a URL, you are providing a dom element.

There are lots of examples of ["jquery ajax form submit"](http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery%20ajax%20form%20submit) on the web.

```
$.ajax({type:'POST', url: '/select', data:$('#searchform').serialize(), success: function(response) {
    $('#content').html(response);
}});
```